# How to sort result in array based on date

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to catch all event for a particuler date.
I have an event result as:

```
{
    "response": {
        "2014-12-13": [
            {
                "id": "16",
                "event_name": "testing",
                "image": "images/Penguins.jpg",
                "event_date": "2014-12-13",
                "event_time": "02:10",
                "time_interval": "4",
                "location": "mohali",
                "event_type": "Rock",
                "detail": "sfdsf fgf ghb\t",
                "delivery": "dggh fghgfh\t\t",
                "status": "1"
            }
        ],
        "2014-12-18": [
            {
                "id": "15",
                "event_name": "hello",
                "image": "images/Desert.jpg",
                "event_date": "2014-12-18",
                "event_time": "02:10",
                "time_interval": "11",
                "location": "sss",
                "event_type": "Simple",
                "detail": "dss sd\t\t",
                "delivery": "asds sffs\t\t",
                "status": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "event_name": "dd",
                "image": "images/Tulips.jpg",
                "event_date": "2014-12-18",
                "event_time": "01:00",
                "time_interval": "sd",
                "location": "wed",
                "event_type": "Simple",
                "detail": "wdd\t\t\t",
                "delivery": "jbd\t\t\t",
                "status": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need, I want to catch each date with a same key to capture these date events in IOS web service, LIKE

```
"event_date" :"2014-12-18": [    //this date have two result

"event_date" :"2014-12-13": [    //this date have oneresult
```

I have tried this code:

```
 if(array_key_exists($data['event_date'],$sortArray))
                    {
                        $sortArray['response'][$data['event_date']][]=$data;
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        $sortArray['response'][$data['event_date']][]=$data;
                    }
```

SO what can I do to make it possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you have two `event_date` keys? they won't share it will overwrite the other

Comment: yes, I am facing this problem

Comment: sorry, but you cannot force the issue, keys are supposed to be unique. but the other way is possible `"2014-12-18: "event_date""`

Comment: It can't resolve my problem, Thanks for your time

Comment: Use usort() function to sort multi-dimensional array.